# Evaluate $\int\frac{x^4}{(x^2-1)^3}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I tried:$$I=\int\frac{x^4}{(x^2-1)^3}dx=\int\frac{(x^2-1)(x^2+1)+1}{(x^2-1)^3}dx=\int\frac{x^2+1}{(x^2-1)^2}+\frac{1}{(x^2-1)^3}dx$$
For first fraction we can write it as $\frac{1}{x^2-1}+\frac{2}{(x^2-1)^2}$. therefor we have:

$$I=\frac12\ln\left|\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right|+\int\frac{2}{(x^2-1)^2}dx+\int\frac{1}{(x^2-1)^3}dx$$

I don't know how to evaluate remaining integrals.

Comment: You can do this by partial fractions.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the form of partial fractions. for first fractions should it be: $$\frac{Ax+B}{(x^2-1)}+\frac{Cx+D}{(x^2-1)^2}$$?

Comment: For the first, $$\frac{A}{x-1} +\frac{B}{(x-1)^2} +\frac{C}{x+1}+\frac{D}{(x+1)^2} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrate by parts to reduce the remaining integrals

$$\int \frac{dx}{(x^2-1)^3}=\int \frac1{4x^3}d\left( \frac{-x^4}{(x^2-1)^2}\right)= -\frac14 \frac{x}{(x^2-1)^2}-\frac34 \int \frac{dx}{(x^2-1)^2}
$$

$$\int \frac{dx}{(x^2-1)^2}=\int \frac1{2x}d\left( \frac{-x^2}{x^2-1}\right)= -\frac12 \frac{x}{x^2-1}-\frac12\int \frac{dx}{x^2-1}
$$

Comment: How do you recognized this integral by parts? it was impossible for me to see it!

Comment: @philomath - admittedly, not obvious; mainly from experience

Answer (score 2):

Another approach: with $x=-\csc t$ the original integral becomes $\int\sec^5tdt$, then use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed#Higher_odd_powers_of_secant) together with $\sec t\tan t=\frac{x}{1-x^2},\,(\sec t+\tan t)^2=\frac{2x-1-x^2}{1-x^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

If the numerator is $x^{2r},$

$$x^{2r}=(1+x^2-1)^r=?$$

Had the numerator been $x^{2r+1},$

$x^{2r+1}=x(1+x^2-1)^r$ first substitute $x^2-1=y$

Now for $S=\dfrac{d(x/(x^2-1)^n)}{dx},$

$S=1/(x^2-1)^n-2(n+1)x^2(x^2-1)^{n+1}$

Write $x^2=x^2-1+1$ and integrate both sides to find

$$\dfrac x{(x^2-1)^n}=I(n)-2(n+1)(I (n) - I(n+1))$$ where $I(m)=\displaystyle\int\dfrac{dx}{(x^2-1)^m}$

Can you identify the values of  $n$ here?